# Javascript Object.innerHtml is not substituting the whole string parameter provided

Tags: javascript, html

`newcell.innerHTML='<td id=\"blah1\">'+BLAH+'</td>';`
For some strange reason my `<td>BLAH</td>` is correctly rendered on the page but any attributes that I give inside the td tag just don't display. Any pointers?
Sorry if this might sound very silly, I have very less experience in front end. Any 'must look' tutorials would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this the actual test code you're running, or is it a simplified example?

Comment: What is `BLAH` here? If is meant to be the `td` content, then you should use `'BLAH'` instead of `BLAH`. If it is a variable, what does it contain?

Comment: BLAH is a variable. The value of BLAH is correctly rendered in the html.

Comment: One more question - is `newcell` a `td` itself?

Comment: Because if `newcell` _is_ a `td` then you're trying to set a `td` inside a `td`. This is invalid HTML, and all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

If `newCell` in this case represents a `<td>` then you need to either use `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML`, or programmatically set the properties you need.

```
var newCell = document.createElement("td");
newCell.outerHTML = '<td id=\"blah1\">'+BLAH+'</td>';
```

or

```
var newCell = document.createElement("td");
newCell.id = "blah1";
newCell.innerHTML = BLAH;
```

Comment: I used outerHTML, the <td> was correctly rendered but again without any attributed.
What do you mean by 'programmatically' setting the properties?

Comment: See my second example for programmatically setting the properties.  If these solutions don't work, maybe you could provide some more context in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're declaring a Javascript string with single quotes, you don't need to escape any double-quotes that you use inside it. Try `newcell.innerHTML='<td id="blah1">'+BLAH+'</td>';`.

Comment: Escaping the double-quotes, while it isn't required, is still legal and works.  'hello \"world\"' === 'hello "world"'

Comment: I was playing it safe by escaping even when I'm using single-double quote nesting. As @BryanKyle said, it is legal, but I still don't get any attributes :(